# Tag aliases for training courses and career advice

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tag-synonyms

Such as:

- [training-courses](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training-courses) → [courses](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/courses)
- [career-advice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-advice) and [career-guidance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-guidance) → [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career)

or perhaps let more users suggest synonyms (e.g. by factoring in SO/total(SE) reputation).

Answer (score 2):

I would rather we merge [courses](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/courses) into [training-courses](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training-courses) to prevent ambiguity.

We need to do something about [career-advice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-advice) and [career-guidance](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-guidance) beyond/instead of merging it into [career](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career): career advice is [off-topic here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) except in very specific circumstances. I'm even going to go out on a limb and say they're pointless meta-tags: all on-topic questions here are necessarily about programming as a career, and having separate tags for advice and guidance only serves to reinforce the idea that asking for *advice* and *guidance*, as opposed to *answers*, is okay.

Comment: I disagree that all on-topic questions are about programming as a career. Career development is not off-topic (although questions have to be phrased in a way that's applicable to a general audience -- nothing new there from other topics), and questions that fall into that category are quite different from questions about, say, algorithm design. That said, I agree that `career-advice` and `career-guidance` themselves are pointless tags. Questions using them should be reviewed to see if the fit existing guidelines and retagged or closed as needed.